# "In fulfilling"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> ... the neglected child might become a psychologically dependent adult
>   continually seeking the oral stimulation denied in infancy, thereby
>   becoming a manipulative person ***in fulfilling*** his or her needs,
>   rather than maturing to independence... ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_stage))

What does "in fulfilling" mean here? I would use "for fulfilling" or "to fulfil" in the place of the marked phrase above. Do they mean the same thing if I replace them with that phrase?

Comment: No—for...or to... designates a goal, in... designates a state in which the becoming happens. _In grieving, we come to terms with what has changed our life and how our life has changed._

Comment: Hmm. Can I change "in" with "by" here?

Comment: No ))) "by fulfilling" would designate a means by which the becoming comes about. Mind, I'm not a native speaker, so I may be wrong )))

Answer (score 1):

The OED has the following definition of *in* with examples underneath:

> In the process of, in the act of; in case of: often equivalent in sense to a temporal clause introduced by *when*, *while*, *if*, *in the event of*.

> - **1477 Earl Rivers (Caxton) Dictes 67** Gladdenesse, whiche encresses daily in me in lernynghe wysdom.
> - **? a 1550 Life Fisher in F.'s Wks. (E.E.T.S.) II. p. liii,** I am not affraid in gevinge you this counsell to take vpon my owne soul all the damage.
> - **1591 Shakes. 1 Hen. VI, v. iii. 41** And may ye both be sodainly surpriz'd By bloudy hands, in sleeping on your beds.
> - **1596 ― Merch. V. iii. ii. 320** In paying it, it is impossible I should liue.
> - **1607 Stat. in Hist. Wakefield Gram. Sch. (1892) 58** Leaves word thereof att their howses in theire beinge abrode.
> - **1846 MCulloch Acc. Brit. Empire (1854) II. 217** In estimating the chances which any candidate has of succeeding..no one ever thinks of inquiring into the politics of the tenants.
> - **1864 Holme Lee In Silver Age (1866) 408** Kindness is not a quality that perishes in the using.

---

*In* is pretty much synonymous with *in the process of* in that sentence, carrying the meaning of contemporaneousness. The sentence says that when such a person is in the process of fulfilling their needs, they exhibit manipulativeness. It would be *technically wrong* to equate it with the statement that they use manipulativeness *in order to* fulfill their needs, although that can be its consequence, so most people wouldn't notice if you swapped *in fulfilling* with *to fulfill* in this case, I think.

Comment: Thank you. Is usage of "in" in those sentence above an old-fashioned way to use? Can we rewrite those sentences without using "in" while keeping meaning the same?

Comment: @TalhaÖzden Oh, the OED's sentences are ancient, but don't worry about that; this use of *in* hasn't disappeared, and there are no signs of mold on it, although it doesn't come across as informal. *In the process of* can be used to replace *in* in the original.

Comment: If you were to write a formal essay, would you use "in" or "in the process of" ?

Comment: @TalhaÖzden *In the process of* is already overly verbose and maybe a little stilted in that sentence. I only used it to explain the meaning of *in*. Anyway, I'd use *in*.